# Realm with GCD using

Tags: database, multithreading, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working at client-server app. I'm sending request, after got response going to backgound thread to parse data, after all data parsed, i'm going to main thread. All data wrote in realm transaction exists in background thread but in main thread it is empty. this is part of my code:
at start I have 20 objects

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        guard let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            else {
                completion(response: false)
                return
        }
        if dictionary["status"] != nil {
            completion(response: false)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
            print("\(NSDate()) start parse feeds with offset")
            self.parseArticle(dictionary, data: [])
            print("\(NSDate()) finish parse feeds with offset")
            UserSession.feedsLoaded = true
            //here I have 40 objects
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //here I have again 20 objects, which I had at start
                completion(response: true)
            })
        })
    })


    func parseArticle(dictionary : [String : AnyObject], data : [String]) {
    var startData = data
    var endData : [String] = []
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let _ = try? realm.write() {here is the code of my parser}}
```

The problem that data commited in background thread doesn't appear in realm in main thread, how can I manage it?

Comment: what is the question? please update your post

Comment: the question is, where is the data added to realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Realm's docs on [Seeing Changes from Other Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads).

You'll need to call `Realm.refresh()` or wait for the next runloop iteration if `autorefresh` is `true` to see the changes in your main thread.